# Does Spock's appearance reflect the fact that he is only half-Vulcan?

Tags: star-trek, vulcan, spock

We know that Spock is biologically half-Vulcan but to me he looks just like full-Vulcans. B'Elanna Torres is half-Klingon and half-human, but in her case you can tell; the Klingon traits like head ridges are about 50% of what they would be were she a full-Klingon. So, shouldn't Spock have only *kind of* pointy ears, *sort of* slanted eye-brows, *slightly green* blood, etc. instead of simply looking just like a full-Vulcan?

Comment: Perhaps he has his father's ears and his mother's pancreas, or something.

Comment: I have the sense that, early on, non-Spock Vulcans tended to have much more dramatic eyebrows (see, e.g., [Sonak](http://vignette3.wikia.nocookie.net/memoryalpha/images/f/fa/Sonak.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20090601012839&path-prefix=en) from TMP), but that this was toned down in later movies and TNG-era Trek. This may just be confirmation bias, though...

Comment: I think Spock was originally conceived as fully Vulcan and re-imagined as half-human somewhere in the first season. "This Side of Paradise" (something like ep 24 of season 1) contains dialog in which Kirk points out his half-breed nature. However, in "Balance of Terror" (ep 14), Lt. Stiles' comments about Spock's resemblance to Romulans implies that Spock is pure Vulcan.

Comment: Note that not all genetic traits "mix", many of them fully reflect the genes from only one parent.

Comment: @AnthonyX: Spock references his human heritage in the second pilot, *Where No Man Has Gone Before*, just after Kirk surprises him with an unexpected chess move: Kirk: "Certain you don't know what irritation is?" Spock: "The fact one of my ancestors married a human female..." We learn later, of course, that the ancestor in question was his father. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Good catch. But I stand by my assertion that he was initially conceived as fully alien (original pilot), despite his displays of emotion. Even though, as you say, he referenced his mixed heritage in the second pilot, I think some of the first season episodes were written with the notion that he is fully Vulcan, or at least in denial of any human heritage.

Comment: @AnthonyX: "he was initially conceived as fully alien (original pilot)" - hmm, but already in an [early draft proposal for Star Trek from March 1964](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Trek_is...), Spock is described as "Probably half Martian". It seems that the idea that he is only partially alien was around pretty early.

Answer (score 14):

In the original *Star Trek*, Spock's appearance was simply that of a human with oddly trimmed eyebrows, green-tinted skin, and pointed ears.

[image: Spock]

In contrast, his father Sarek has much heavier eyebrows, much more oddly pointed ears, and a heavier coat of green makeup which additionally gave his skin an uneven quality.

[image: Sarek]

When I first saw the episode "Journey to Babel," in which Sarek appears, as a kid, I was immediately struck by how much more alien a full-blooded Vulcan looked than Spock.

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but from the photos you're showing it is not directly obvious to me that Sarek's ears are "much more oddly pointed" and that he's wearing a "heavier coat of green makeup".

Comment: Also the skin thing could be explained with age. After all, he is Spok's father.

Comment: @Emil I think the "makeup" might even be just imagination based on the lighting. But his ears are clearly not as straight as Spock's. Just compare the outer edge. Of course this might be unintentional and also based on camera angle, lighting, etc.

Comment: @Emil [Ears](http://vignette3.wikia.nocookie.net/startrek/images/4/48/Sarek_2268.jpg) and [Eyebrows](http://trekcore.com/gallery/albums/sarek/sarek_st4pb.jpg) are much more pronounced.  You can't see his eyebrows well in the above picture, because they're grey. They almost touch his hairline, while Spock looks like he just plucks his eyebrows' outer halves.

Comment: @Mario The pictures in the answer were just ones I found randomly on the Internet.  They are not necessarily reliable depictions of Spock's and Sarek's skin colors in the original broadcasts.  The original Stark Trek episodes have been competely remastered, and they made "improvements" to much of the makeup work and special effects.  It would not surprise me if they played with Sarek's skin tone to make it closer to the more understated makeup they used on Mark Lenard in post-1960s appearances.

Comment: If you could provide more comparisons as evidence I'd be willing to accept this answer. I'm afraid two pictures, one of spock, one of another vulcan, aren't quite enough to support the conclusion you've put forth.